# With Ruby, does "gem install" use "--include-dependencies"... just the doc is a little outdated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Using Ruby on Rails, if I do a

```
gem help install
```

a part of it says:

```
-y, --include-dependencies       Unconditionally install the required
                                 dependent gems

[...]

Defaults:
  --both --version '>= 0' --rdoc --ri --no-force
  --no-test --install-dir c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

but if I do a

```
gem install --include-dependencies mysql
```

a line says:

```
INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed
INFO:  use --ignore-dependencies to install only the gems you list
```

so looks like `gem install` always use `--include-dependencies` now?  Just the docs of `gem help install` is a little outdated?

I am using the most recent gem:

```
C:\>gem -v
1.3.7

C:\>gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Nothing to update

C:\>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is a bit outdated.

gem install --include-dependencies option has been default for some time now.

Comment: It seems that as of Gem 2.0, `-y` and `--include-dependencies` have been removed completely and now trigger an **ERROR: invalid option**

Answer (score 6):

The command is now `-include-dependencies`, not `--include-dependencies`
I have used it this way:

I have tried to install compass 0.12.3 dependencies and I have done it with this command, but this installed only dependencies not compass with them

```
gem install compass -v 0.12.3 -include-dependencies
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I tried keeping that -include-dependencies tag at the end, then just after the gemname and then just after install. In all the cases it says "unable to find the gem". But if I try without the command then it installs the gem fine (except for the dependencies). Ruby sucks!

Comment: If you use this it will install your gems in `nclude-dependencies` directory.

Comment: this is like `gem install compass -v 0.12.3 -i 'nclude-dependencies'` and creates that weird directory `nclude-dependencies` with all the dependencies in it.